# Customization of checkbox in android

Tags: android

I have couple of questions regarding checkbox customization.

1)I have a selector for checkbox in xml which I have used to replace small box of checkbox with the image. I want dim colored image when the checkbox is 
selected. I have 2 images for that. I am wondering if i can dim the image using code from java or xml so that only one image will work?

customdrawablecheckbox.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/bike_sm"/>
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/bike_sm_dim" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bike_sm" /> <!-- default state -->
</selector>
```

2)How can I scale the customized checkbox image from above selector so that it's width fits 1/3rd of the screen width?

3)I have set text in the checkbox as well. I want to set it below the image. I am using checkBoxhh.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.customdrawablecheckbox). 
But i didnt find anything to set checkbox text below image. However I used setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds to achieve it but the default small box with tick mark also appears here.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:id="@+id/pLayout"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
</LinearLayout>
```

Activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_compare);

    linearLayout1 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.pLayout);

    String strJson="{"root":[{"bikes":[{"name":"p220","image_url":""},{"name":"p200","image_url":""},{"name":"p150","image_url":""}]}]}";

    String data = "";
    JSONObject jsonRootObject = null;
    try {
        jsonRootObject = new JSONObject(strJson);
        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonRootObject.optJSONArray("root");

        for(int i=0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            JSONArray jsonArray1 = jsonObject.optJSONArray("bikes");

            for (j=0; j < jsonArray1.length();j++){
                JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray1.getJSONObject(j);
                String name = jsonObject1.optString("name").toString();
                checkBoxhh = new CheckBox(this);
                checkBoxhh.setId(j);
                checkBoxhh.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.customdrawablecheckbox);
                //the commented code below puts the image at top of text but the tick 
                //mark is also seen which I don't want

                //Drawable d =getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.customdrawablecheckbox);
                //checkBoxhh.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null,d,null,null);

                checkBoxhh.setText(name);
                linearLayout1.addView(checkBoxhh);
            }
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1)no need

2)Just change the size of `CheckBox`

3)Just set them to `@null`

```
<CheckBox
        android:drawableTop="@android:drawable/checkbox_on_background"
        android:button="@null"
        android:drawablePadding="3dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@null"
        android:text="111"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp" />
```

[image]

Edit:

1)If you really want to do and the images have only one color,you can use

```
supportv4
```

and

```
public static Drawable tintDrawable(Drawable drawable, ColorStateList colors) {
    final Drawable wrappedDrawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(drawable);
    DrawableCompat.setTintList(wrappedDrawable, colors);
    return wrappedDrawable;
}
```

2)

```
checkBoxhh.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(getScreenWidth()/3,getScreenWidth()/3));
linearLayout1.addView(checkBoxhh);
```

3) just use `setCompoundDrawables` like your code.

Comment: hello sunlight... For q. 3 - The checkboxes should be added dynamically (ie programmatically from java not xml) and I want image instead of the tick mark. For q.2 - how to change the size of checkbox. I need to do it from java. I tried setScale etc (doesn't work). For q. 1 - why no need? I have a lot of checkboxes and I don't want to have 3 images of each checkbox. Plz hav a look at my Activity codes.